# Is there a way to create a select option fields that shows a table list using filament v3.0?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-filament

I want the table list to show in the page when I selected one of the options. I try to use the afterStateUpdated() but I only shows the text input, I want to show the list coming from the eloquent relationship instead. I am using laravel 10, filament V3.0 and one to many relationship for this task.

The code example is coming from the filament oficial website.

```
 use Filament\Forms\Components\FileUpload;

 use Filament\Forms\Components\Grid;
 use Filament\Forms\Components\Select;
 use Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput;
 use Filament\Forms\Get;



Select::make('type')
    ->options([
        'employee' => 'Employee',
        'freelancer' => 'Freelancer',
    ])
    ->live()
    ->afterStateUpdated(fn (Select $component) => $component
        ->getContainer()
        ->getComponent('dynamicTypeFields')
        ->getChildComponentContainer()
        ->fill())
    
Grid::make(2)
    ->schema(fn (Get $get): array => match ($get('type')) {
        'employee' => [
            TextInput::make('employee_number')
                ->required(),
            FileUpload::make('badge')
                ->image()
                ->required(),
        ],
        'freelancer' => [
            TextInput::make('hourly_rate')
                ->numeric()
                ->required()
                ->prefix('€'),
            FileUpload::make('contract')
                ->required(),
        ],
        default => [],
    })
    ->key('dynamicTypeFields')
```

Thank your time and consideration.